# Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsError at Compile Time

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jvm

So the intellij compiler is breaking on compile. From my understanding, index out of bounds is a runtime error. How can it happen at compile time? Here is what I am trying to compile for a ScalaTest:

```
class ConfigurationTest extends FlatSpec{
  behavior of "Configuration"
  it should "have a full configuration" in {
  val dashboard = ConfigurationService.getDashboardConfig("1")
  val dTest = write(dashboard)
  val mockFormat =//Really long Json Object as a string >6000 lines


  val testObj = read[JDashboard](mockFormat)
  assert(dTest.equals(mockFormat))
}
 implicit var formats = org.json4s.native.Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
}
```

Since it builds outside of intellij I am assuming that intellij's internal jvm has a limit somewhere but why would this happen?

Comment: Does it compile outside of IntelliJ with sbt?

Comment: @joescii it does bu gives an unknown constant tag 116 error